# MudRating lost value in dynamic list item

Tags: blazor, mudblazor

I have a page wit a list of element get from a search. The list is dynamic.

On each element, I want add `MudRating` to rate element... but when the list is refreshed, the rate is lost... (or take the value from a other element, not sure).

I see this behavior only on `MudRating`.

To reproduce, create a new MudBlazor project with :

```
dotnet new mudblazor --host wasm --name MyApplication
```

Replace the content of **Pages\Index.razor** :

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<MudList>
    <MudNumericField @bind-Value="skip" Label="Skip" Variant="Variant.Text" Min="0" />
    <MudListSubheader>
        Result :
    </MudListSubheader>
    @foreach (var item in Items.Skip(skip))
    {
        <MudListItem>
            <p>@item.Id</p>
            <MudRating @bind-SelectedValue="item.Rate" />
        </MudListItem>
    }
</MudList>

@code
{
    int skip;
    IEnumerable<Dto> Items = Enumerable.Range(0, 15).Select(i => new Dto { Id = i, Rate = i % 6 }).ToList();

    class Dto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Rate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then run the app :

```
dotnet run
```

If you play with the skip (to simulate a search), you will see the rating has a weird behavior.

Can you explain the weird behavior?

How avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation :

> [Use @key to control the preservation of elements and components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-8.0#use-key-to-control-the-preservation-of-elements-and-components)
>
> When rendering a list of elements or components and the elements or components subsequently change, Blazor must decide which of the previous elements or components are retained and how model objects should map to them. Normally, this process is automatic and sufficient for general rendering, but there are often cases where controlling the process using the @key directive attribute is required.

The solution is to use `@key` directive like :

```html
@foreach (var item in Items.Skip(skip))
{
    <MudListItem @key="item">
        <p>@item.Id</p>
        <MudRating @bind-SelectedValue="item.Rate" />
    </MudListItem>
}
```